# Why I got an error 500 internal server when I deploy my Django project?

Tags: django, django-errors

I just deploy my Django project in cpanel and now when I want to use my RegisterView to create a user after I POST JSON data with the register field required, the user is created in the database but it gives me a

My RegisterView:

```
class RegisterView(APIView):
    """
    Register a new user.
    """
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        """
        Getting the user's information for register.
        """
        try:
            email = request.data["email"]
            username = request.data["username"]
            password = request.data["password"]
            confirm_password = request.data["confirm_password"]
            full_name = request.data["full_name"]
            simple_description = request.data["simple_description"]
            biography = request.data["biography"]
            profile_picture = request.FILES.get("profile_picture")

            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                return Response(data={"error": "Email has been already used."},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                return Response(data={"error": "Username has been already used."},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            if password != confirm_password:
                return Response(data={"error": "Passwords do not match."},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            
            user = User.objects.create(
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=password,
                full_name=full_name,
                simple_description=simple_description,
                biography=biography,
            )

            if profile_picture:
                user.profile_picture = profile_picture
                user.save()

            Notification.objects.create(
                author=user,
                title="Create account",
                description=CREATE_ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION
            )

            return Response(data={'message': 'User has been successfully created.'},
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        except RequestException:
            return Response(data={"error": "An error occurred. Please check your internet connection."},
                            status=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
```

The JSON data i posted:

```
{
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "password": "password123",
    "confirm_password": "password123",
    "full_name": "John Doe",
    "simple_description": "Tourist",
    "biography": "I love traveling.",
    "username": "johndoe"
}
```

I tied to create a user in the admin panel and still gives me this error

Comment: Show  your error trace back?

Comment: Actually, I understand why I get this error.
 (OperationalError at /api/register/
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD8\\xA8\\xD9\\x87 \\xD8...' for column 'description' at row 1")) 
It's because I used Persian text in the description. can you help me with how can i support the Persian language in my project?